# Prevent unmounting of react-navigation stacknavigator screen

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I have Screen A (Dashboard) and Screen B (Details).

When you click on a button in the dashboard you get navigated to details. This is done with a react-navigation (v1.5) stackrouter. When you navigate back the detail screen gets unmounted and you go back to the dashboard.

Is it possible to keep the details screen mounted when you navigate back?

Comment: Did you find anything useful about it?

Answer (score 0):

Try using the latest react-navigation v3. With that the stackNavigator will not unmount the component during navigations. Example

```
import React from 'react';
import { Button, View, Text } from 'react-native';
import { createStackNavigator, createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';

class HomeScreen extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
        <Text>Home Screen</Text>
        <Button
          title="Go to Details"
          onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Details')}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Hey, thanks! As far as I understand v3 will still unmount the details  when navigating back from details => home?

Comment: ah yep the component WILL get unmounted if it's the topmost on the stack and you pop if off. Popping the component off can be done with navigate (to a route that is the second from the top), .pop(), .popToTop() and maybe some methods. If you really want to keep them around you should use a custom navigator or move your state out of the components.

Comment: Yes, I was looking into the custom navigator route. The reason I need the component to stay mounted is because it is a webview that is controlled with some injected javascript. On each mount the webview will load the page again and this can take +10 seconds (don't ask why :)).

Comment: @YvoCilon You got any solution for this?

Comment: I'll add that since the date of this answer react-navigation has moved on to v5 and the apis are very different.